Job for named.service failed because the control process exited with error code . See "systemctl status named.service"

After starting the dns service I am getting below errors. I am trying to resolve but am unable to.

Don't post images when plain text will do.

and what basic steps did you to get more information to solve it, what research has already been done? please also read carefully [ask]

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
